# Select two table and put ordering priority

Tags: php, mysql

I have two tables, 
`ir1_police` is included messages that reported to admin.
`ir1_police_flag`, admin can flag reporters from 1 to 2. (1 means medium 2 means low and nothing means high priority).

If someone try to report something that is not real. Admin will flag it as 1 or 2 .
So I would make a list of report that shows first high priority, second medium and at last low.

I use the mysql statement but there is a problem. if there was nothing `ir1_police_report` nothing will be shown. or if exist only shows they are on `ir_police_flags`.

I have no idea to select them if no record exists on `ir1_police_flags`

```
SELECT * FROM ir1_police 
JOIN ir1_police_flags on ir1_police_flags.uid = `ir1_police.uid 
WHERE 
ir1_police.status=0 AND ir1_police.parent_id=0 
ORDER BY ir1_police.time DESC
```

Comment: `ORDER BY ir1_police_flags.flag ASC, irw_police.time DESC`

Comment: The problem is if there was nothing on ir1_police_flags , nothing will be shown/ but i need to show everything that should be shown for ir1_police . also if there was anything on ir1_police_flags show beside equals user id

Comment: Also in addition to @Mike comment, use left join if there does not need to be record in ir1_police_flags for highest priority

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace `JOIN`with `LEFT JOIN`. The former only selects rows from the tables where a match is found, whereas the latter selects all rows from the first table, even when there is no match in the other table.

Then you can add a second field to `ORDER BY`:

```
SELECT * FROM ir1_police
LEFT JOIN ir1_police_flags ON ir1_police_flags.uid = ir1_police.uid
WHERE ir1_police.status=0 AND ir1_police.parent_id=0 
ORDER BY
    ir1_police_flags.flag ASC,
    ir1_police.time DESC
```

Notice the `LEFT JOIN` produces results where all `ir1_police_flags`'s fields are `NULL` where there is no match in this table. This is perfect in your case, because `NULL` is considered smaller than any value, as far as `ORDER BY` is concerned.

---

Your application might justify this structure, but you should ask yourself whether this flag shouldn't be just a column in the table `ir1_police` altogether.